# What is XAML generated break on unhandled exception and app.g.i.cs file

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-phone, win-universal-app

I am new to windows app development. I am trying to execute a solution on my local machine using x64 platform. But whenever I execute a Buttom_Click event I am getting this exception

```
#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION
            UnhandledException += (sender, e) =>
            {
                if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break();
            };
#endif
```

in App.g.i.cs file.

I am getting this exception when debugger hits the variable 'icon' below

```
 private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            RootObject myWeather =
                await OpenWeatherMapProxy.GetWeather(20.0,30.0);

            string icon = String.Format("ms-appx:///Assets/Weather/{0}.png", myWeather.weather[0].icon);
            ResultImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(icon, UriKind.Absolute));
            ResultTextBlock.Text = myWeather.name + " - " + ((int)myWeather.main.temp).ToString() + " - " + myWeather.weather[0].description;
        }
```

It would be helpful if anyone can explain how to get rid of this exception and what is App.g.i.cs file.

Comment: It is null at 'string icon =....' but debugger is not even hitting the line 'Result image = ...'  and exception is being thrown

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`App.g.i.cs` is an auto genearated file, and its breaking at that location because you haven't handled the exception properly in your code.

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try{

    RootObject myWeather =
        await OpenWeatherMapProxy.GetWeather(20.0,30.0);

    string icon = String.Format("ms-appx:///Assets/Weather/{0}.png", myWeather.weather[0].icon);
    ResultImage.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(icon, UriKind.Absolute));
    ResultTextBlock.Text = myWeather.name + " - " + ((int)myWeather.main.temp).ToString() + " - " + myWeather.weather[0].description;

    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
       Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
       Debug.WriteLine(ex.StackTrace);
    }
}
```

Go to the Output window when the application is running and go through the exception detail, you might find the answer.

Mostlikely exception is causeded by `myWeather` or `myWeather.weather[0]` being null because `OpenWeatherMapProxy.GetWeather` failed to fetch the data.

Comment: Appreciate your reply, now it is clear what should I be doing to handle correctly. I did as you told and when I combined the results of exceptions in output window, it boils down to this                                                                                                      " Object reference not set to an instance of an object at TestWeather.MainPage.<Button_Click>d__1.MoveNext() "  But I never implemented MoveNext() method and it is no where to be found in solution as well.

Comment: Can you post the entire stacktrace?

Comment: at TestWeather.MainPage.<Button_Click>d__1.MoveNext()  That is the entire stacktrace.

Comment: thats not the stack trace... it gives the whole path of the calls.

Comment: which version of .Net is your project running on?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103428/discussion-between-coder221-and-carbinecoder).

Comment: GetWeather method was not returning value. Now I was able to solve it by correcting api url .

Comment: An alternate solution is to turn on first-chance exceptions in the Debug Settings; that obviates the need to add `try`/`catch` throughout your code.