# NuGet requires TargetPlatformVersion >= 10.0.18362.0 that doesn't exist or cannot be installed?

Tags: visual-studio, uwp

I installed the latest updates from NuGet. As can be seen, my app is required to be targeted to version 18362, but my highest is 17763 (the minimum version is the same as the target version):

[image]

So I checked Visual Studio Installer, but there doesn't seem to be anything newer available:

[image]

Visual Studio is up to date. I cannot build because the warning throws an error at build time. What am I missing?

Comment: What's your os version?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT Version 1909 OS build 18363.535

Comment: Please try to install latest  [Windows 10 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk) version.

Comment: Does it work after install the latest Windows 10 SDK?

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT It was necessary to uninstall the previous SDK, but it does now show the build number. Though my app was functioning properly before, I'm now experiencing this error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35392931/what-is-xaml-generated-break-on-unhandled-exception-and-app-g-i-cs-file

Comment: Please try to clean your solution and delete bin and obj folder and try again.

Comment: @NicoZhu-MSFT I did that but get the same result.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204916/discussion-between-denis-g-labrecque-and-nico-zhu-msft).

Comment: Currently you could create higher version project, but Microsoft.UI.Xaml  package cause the issue right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> NuGet requires TargetPlatformVersion >= 10.0.18362.0 that doesn't exist or cannot be installed?

The problem is that you have not install 18362 [Windows 10 SDK](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk). please check this link and install latest SDK version.

> I'm now experiencing this error

For your new error, Please try to clean your solution and delete bin and obj folder, or edit debug platform and edit the target min version for your project.

And please note, you need add the following to your application resource.

For more please refer this case [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59244811/7254781).