# E Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Non-negative number required. (Parameter 'width') Sender Applinks

Tags: c#, maui

1. ISsues is this does not show up as normal exception come to this app.g.i.cs this line
   `#if DEBUG && !DISABLE_XAML_GENERATED_BREAK_ON_UNHANDLED_EXCEPTION UnhandledException += (sender, e) => { if (global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached) global::System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Break(); };`

I have to check my locals and get sender and e

2. The sender is applinks and the error is Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Non-negative number required. (Parameter 'width') When i drop down exception there is no stack trace or inner exception

I dug deep into sender and error objects and unable to track down what is causing this.

Comment: Could you provide some code to reproduce like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35392931/what-is-xaml-generated-break-on-unhandled-exception-and-app-g-i-cs-file)?